# escape comma and add new column while creating a csv file

Tags: php, regex, csv

I am converting a Delimited FLAT file to CSV and it has some data which as comma in between them. For eg the product name Iphone 6splus, 32 gb. Since this a description of the product and can have special characters also. How do i escape the comma as because of this `fputcsv` is considering this data as a new line. which is wrong. I am using

```
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");
$lines = [];
$row_count=0;
if (($handle = fopen("data.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        if($row_count>0)
        {
                    $lines[] = $data;
        }
        $row_count++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$fp = fopen('example.csv', 'w');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, split('\*\*', $line));
}
fclose($fp);
```

I need to escape the value before i start converting the data and store into csv

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the field in quotes, e.g.

```
field1_value,field2_value,"field 3,value",field4, etc...
```

To encode a quote, use ", a single quote symbol in a field will be encoded as "", and the whole field will become """". So if you see the following in e.g. Excel:

```
---------------------------------------
| regular_value |,,,"|  ,"", |"""   |"|
---------------------------------------
```

the CSV file will contain:

regular_value,",,,""",","""",","""""""",""""
A comma is simply encapsulated using quotes, so , becomes ",".

A command and quote needs to be encapsulated and quoted, so "," becomes """,""".